# Lost more rep, after user removal loss

Tags: support

The user rep numbers have gone wonky in the last few weeks. Some new change on AU caused the problem(s). The numbers don't always add up any more.

Here's an example...

My summary rep shows only +10.

My detail shows +35.

Everything AFTER the "User was removed" isn't counted.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The number in the green bubble shows only net reputation gain since you last checked. See how it matches the 127 next to the Reputation tab title bottom right of this screenshot:

[image: 127 in green bubble before checking rep tab]

I go to the rep tab (this counts as checking my rep) and the bubble is still there:

[image: bubble still there]

Back to the summary and the bubble has gone (because I haven't gained any rep since I last checked a few seconds ago).

[image: 127 bubble gone]

So that number in the green bubble isn't a summary of the reputation over any particular time period, except the period since you last checked the reputation tab. That is the only event the number has a reference to.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's supposed to work. And it's always worked that way, until a few weeks ago. Now even refreshing the page doesn't make the summary match the detail. My current bubble shows +24, and the detail shows +49.

Comment: The detail in the reputation tab has nothing to do with the bubble really, as the detail does not track when you last viewed it like the bubble does

Comment: I should probably have described this better... it's not the rep tab, it's the rep detail provided by the icon in the top bar of the web page. I'm off for a 4 day mini-vacation... so I'll check back in later.

Comment: enjoy your vacation!

Comment: I did! Too short... but good enough for now :-) Treated myself to a few good restaurants, spent a little money, had a nice time.

Comment: The rep counters are back to normal now. Everything works as it used to :-)

Comment: that's good to know!